# AdjustWindowRect documentation

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

The MSDN Library documents the dwStyle argument of AdjustWindowRect as:

> The window style of the window whose required size is to be calculated. Note that you cannot
>   specify the WS_OVERLAPPED style.

I haven't found any explanation for this. What do they mean by "cannot" and why can't I do it?

Comment: "cannot" means that if you do, the function will return zero and GetLastError will return invalid parameter.

Comment: Okay. But why is this? It seems like a perfectly sensible thing to do in my opinion.

Comment: That style means "I don't care, you figure it out".  Which is why it is zero.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `WS_OVERLAPPED` style is defined as zero:

```
#define WS_OVERLAPPED    0x00000000L
```

`AdjustWindowRect()` is checking the style flags supplied and modifies the RECT accordingly:

```
// ...
if( dwStyle & WS_BORDER ) {
    const int cx = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXBORDER);
    const int cy = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYBORDER);
    lpRect->top -= cy;
    lpRect->left -= cx;
    lpRect->right += cx;
    lpRect->bottom += cy;
}
// ...
```

Therefore `AdjustWindowRect()` with the dwStyle parameter set to `0` does not alter the lpRect, hence `WS_OVERLAPPED` cannot be used.

If you wish to calculate the size for a top-level frame, you can use `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` or `WS_CAPTION|WS_THICKFRAME` instead.